# Why can I boot from an NTFS USB flash drive?

Tags: boot, ntfs, uefi

I own multiple PC and on some of them, I am able to boot to Windows installer using a USB flash drive formatted in NTFS (same one for all the PC), but not for others.

PC that I have tried this on:

- (able to boot from NTFS) Desktop with motherboard ASUS PRIME Z390-A and a 9th-Gen Intel Core processor
- (not able to boot from NTFS) Surface Pro (5/1796) with i7-7660U (a 7th-Gen) and corresponding motherboard
- (able to boot from NTFS) ASUS ROG Zephyrus M (GM501) with Intel HM370 Chipset and i7-8750H (an 8th-Gen processor)

All of them have CSM disabled (or simply unavailable) and the USB has a GUID Partition Table (GPT) and only a single primary partition.

From the information I gathered online, UEFI-based PC will only boot from an EFI System Partition or a FAT32 partition. But the evidence from my experience clearly tells me otherwise.

Why is that?

Comment: UEFI motherboards will boot WinPE/WinRE from an NTFS formatted partition on Windows 10, however I can't provide what happens on the backend within the Windows bootloader - that information is accessible on Microsoft Docs within their Manufacturer related docs. It used to be that Win10 required a FAT32 formatted drive to boot WinPE/WinRE on UEFI motherboards, however than changed ~2017ish to NTFS.  _(I don't know why the change occurred, but this should also be able to be found on Microsoft Docs or TechNet.)_

Comment: @JW0914 I see. So it's a change in the specification from Microsoft's end. And I guess the timing makes sense too (since ~2017 is about the time where most of the PC's are UEFI-based by default (as opposed to BIOS or UEFI-with-CSM by default).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEFI uses file system drivers to access boot volumes - and the only **required** driver is FAT (12, 16 and 32). This allows for more drivers to be loaded from a FAT partition, working its way up to boot an OS system partition, that is formatted in a different file system.

Of course nothing stops a vendor from integrating more drivers directly into his UEFI implementation - as obviously some of you examples are doing.

Comment: AFAIK, something in the Windows bootloader changed ~2017ish to allow booting WinPE/WinRE from NTFS on UEFI motherboards... I'm not sure what changed, just that before the change, a USB drive had to be formatted as FAT32 in Rufus _(using a Win10 installer ISO)_ to EFI boot WinPE/WinRE, and after the change, NTFS was required and FAT32 wouldn't boot.

Comment: @JW0914 The change you mention is the install image breaking through the 4GB barrier, but it is unrelated: The OQ is about what happens before - how does control flow ever reach a bootloader on an NTFS partition.

Comment: I have zero understanding of the technicalities of bootloaders, but in regards to the first part, I'm not aware of any Windows `install.esd`/`install.wim` exceeding 4GB in size... Microsoft has always been quite intentional about keeping them ~3.8GB in size.  The ISO itself can be >4GB, provided no individual file is, as the ISO itself isn't being copied, it's content is.

Comment: I am at home now, but I am quite positive to have had a 4.2G install.wim last time. I'll take a look on Monday.

Comment: I see, so theoretically a motherboard vendor (like ASUS and MSI) can integrate drivers for many more formats (such as Linux's ext4, Windows Server's ReFS, etc.) into UEFI firmware right? So that explains a lot...

Comment: @JW0914 about the Windows installer's `install.esd` exceeding 4GB - if you use Microsoft's Media Creation Tool and choose "Create a bootable USB stick" option, the `install.esd` file in the flash drive is actually less than 4GB; but if you choose "Create an .iso file" option, the `install.esd` file is larger than 4GB. Btw the Windows version is exactly the same (Which bothers me a lot since that probably means something is left out in the smaller version of `install.esd`)

Comment: It could be, that the compression used is different: ISO optimizes for access speed, while USB for size

Comment: @dragonxi ESD's compression algorithm is ~33% more efficient than WIM's compression algorithm and both the `install.esd` & `install.wim` "_should_" contain the same exact number of indexes [images]: 7 _(index `1` is Home, `6` is Pro)_ - `dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:sources\install.esd`.  I'm not sure why Microsoft is using an `install.wim` if not choosing to create an ISO, but my hunch is Media Creation Tool may be exporting the system applicable index from the `install.esd` as a WIM since Microsoft restricted ESD's usage in Win10 to only PBR [Push-Button Reset] exported images.

Answer (score 0):

install.esd includes integrity hashes for each file instead of the single hash for install.wim when booting from iso.  It is a SECURE software distribution file.  It has to be read in one set and unpacked.

install.wim cannot be loaded read/write until the file system is secured and verified.